# android studio what is the gradle dependencies for opencsv

Tags: android, opencsv

hello guys I hope I'm not repeating any question

So here is my question. what is the gradle dependency for opencsv? when i try to sync my gradle for opencsv, it gives me an error could not download commons-lang3.jar and its many other libraries

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adding this line in build.gradle must work :

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.opencsv:opencsv:4.6'
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Comment: where  get latest version number ?

Comment: @JithishPN `5.6` at the time of writing: http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/summary.html